# How to create GCP VM instance from marketplace's wordpress image with Terraform

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, terraform

How can i create a GCP VM instance with Terraform using `click to deploy images`?

I am trying :

```
data "google_compute_image" "wp_image" {
project = "click-to-deploy-images"
name = "wordpress"
}
boot_disk {
initialize_params {
image = data.google_compute_image.wp_image.id
}
}
```

but getting an error like:

```
Error: error retrieving image information: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/click-to-deploy-images/global/images/wordpress' was not found, notFound
```

I looked many location but couldn't find exact solution.

Note: I am using `Terraform version = "3.48.0"`

Comment: Where did you get the parameters for the image? AFAIK you cannot deploy marketplace images via Terraform. Those images require accepting TOS. However, I am not 100% sure on that point.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley actually i searched a lot this question and found a familiar question at reddit, it wasn't about wordpress. By the way as you know we are using boot disk block to the google_compute_instance_resource.

One of the reddit user answered my question and i want to share with you:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/k4ks6w/how_to_create_gcp_vm_instance_from_marketplaces/geakmh8?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: I do not see how the Reddit post answers your question. Creating an image of an image is not a good strategy and does not solve how to use a Marketplace image in Terraform.

Comment: @JohnHanley but it can be a solution, if there isn't an exact solution.